# Troubleshooting thermionic emission

Tags: electromagnetism, vacuum-tube

I am attempting to make an electron beam device work. The setup is very basic - a wehnelt in a vacuum chamber connected to an AC filament heater source and a DC high voltage source as pictured below. The wehnelts in use are cylindrical objects with small hole on the bottom. The filament is as close by to the hole as possible. Coiled old tungsten wire is used for the filament.

[image]

(The bias is set to 0).

The problem is, there is no visible thermionic emission of any kind from the wehnelt! To troubleshoot, I have

- Measured that the wehnelt is at a high voltage of at least 10 kV. In fact, blueish emissions are emitted in the chamber from the wehnelt holder every so often, possibly from residue.
- Checked that the tungsten filament should be at a high enough temperature based on the yellowish bright color.
- Measured that the anode is connected to the ground.
- Tested multiple different wehnelts, making sure they are close enough (couple cm) to the anode.

The result is perplexing, and I am having difficulty coming up with more modes of failure to check. What more reasons could there be for the setup to not work?

Comment: how are you measuring your emission?

Comment: @MarcusMüller By eye. There should be a gorgeous beam, but something is wrong.

Comment: How high of a vacuum is this vacuum chamber? If it's too high, there won't be any visible emission even when it's working.

Comment: Current should be in the "uA" range ?

Comment: @Hearth The meters may not be very accurate, but the vacuum should be approximately 10^-6 bars, and has worked previously. The anode is copper and should also be affected.

Comment: @Antonio51 Closer to milliamp range <10 mA.

Comment: @Magemathician I don't know the actual dimensions of your tube or how well your thermionic emission *should* work, but the milliampere range sounds overly ambitious. Don't measure by eye, measure by ammeter.

Comment: @Magemathician Have a look at [this 1984 paper](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1024&context=electron). I'm shocked at the vacuum you mention. Even a cheap low-brightness unit needs 10^-8 bar, have a 0.1mm hairpin tip operating at about 2800K (this is critical and not easy to do in a consistent way), and wouldn't expect more 1 uA emitter current. I've also no idea if you are pinching off the current with the bias. Can you write a lot more detail about what in the heck you really have in hand? For lithography where brightness matters, vacuum is much higher.

Comment: @Magemathician Do you have a NIST traceable calibrated disappearing filament pyrometer to use in observing the temperature of the tip? We'd buy calibrated tungsten lamps from NIST (only good for 100 hrs use) and use those to calibrate the pyrometer. Then use the calibrated pyrometer to monitor the filament. (You cannot trust a precision current source as an indirect means of judging temperature.) We'd also use a dual-wavelength pyrometer as a cross-check.

Comment: @Magemathician And what do you mean *"worked previously"*?? What happened to change things on you?

Answer (score 0):

> The two main types of cathode:   (from [this](https://on5vl.org/tension-filament-tubes-emission/))

- Indirectly heated (Nickel substrate covered with Barium and Strontium oxides);
- Directly heated (Tungsten filament **with added Thorium**).

> ... In fact, blueish emissions are emitted in the chamber ...

See first picture in link.

> Indirectly heated cathodes are made up of a refractory insulating sheath that surrounds a Nichrome filament (alloy composed of 80% Nickel and 20% Chrome).
> The sheath is in thermal contact with a Nickel tube on which an alloy of Barium oxide (60%) and Strontium (40%) has been vaporized.
> This alloy of oxides has the particularity of having a very low work function (Richardson’s law).
> Thus, the temperature of the cathode can be set at a value of around 1000 Kelvins.

> During the manufacture of Tungsten wire, 1.5% Thorium is added in the form of oxide (ThO2).
> When the vacuum is created in the tube, a very specific process for manufacturing these tubes makes it possible to migrate Thorium in its metallic form towards the surface of the Tungsten wire forming the filament.
> The emissivity of the filament thus increases by a factor of 1000 (... **until 500 mA/cm2**).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will check this, but I believe I have seen the regular tungsten work previously.

Comment: The emissions are spark-like, and not clouds. Tungsten is mentioned in the following article: https://www.electrical4u.com/thermionic-emission/

Comment: >>> However, tungsten also has a high work function (4.52 eV), which means that it requires a high temperature **(2327 °C)** to emit electrons. This results in a low emission efficiency **(4 mA/W)** and a **short lifetime** due to evaporation and contamination of the cathode surface. Moreover, tungsten emitters have a low surface area, which limits the maximum thermionic current that can be obtained. <<<

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, there is no visible thermionic emission of any kind
> from the wehnelt!

To troubleshoot emission current from the filament, you might try backing-up one step and characterize the diode formed by filament (cathode) to "wehnelt" (haven't seen that term before).
[image: circuit to test emission current]

 You can monitor voltage across the **Bias Resistor** and calculate emission current. The **V_bias** DC supply is *not* high-voltage, but a small low-voltage supply - current requirements of this supply are quite low.

Comment: The wehnelt is just a cylindrical electrode with a pinhole in it, named after its inventor I believe.

Comment: @Hearth OK, thanks - your description does sound like the description of **grid-1** to me. It is the first thing emitted electrons see as they thermeonically bubble off the cathode/filament. The filament tends toward a +ve voltage w.r.t grid. The tiny hole serves as a point-source of electrons that might escape the grid cap. The other point-source of electrons uses cold-cathode tungsten that's been acid-etched to a *very* pointy tip...no grid cap-with-tiny-hole needed.

Comment: @glen_geek Wehnelts in general come in many different shapes, depending on the required beam/application. The size of the holes also varies, in this case the holes are several mm in size. The shape of the surfaces together with the bias resistor acts as to concentrate the beam. Not irrelevant, since the wehnelt surfaces tend to deteriorate over time, and it may be a point of failure.

Comment: @glen_geek The high voltage (and low voltage difference) is fine for normal multimeter?

Comment: Have edited my answer. The **V_bias supply** described shouldn't be high voltage. It might be varied from zero volts up to a few tens of volts...only meant to see if that directly-heated cathode is emitting electrons, and to see how much emission current is generated.